# I got a problem in rest api project in wso2 integration studio

Tags: wso2

I Have this xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<api context="/testapi" name="testapi" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <resource methods="GET" url-mapping="/testapi">
        <inSequence>
            <property expression="get-property('query.param.qp')" name="qp1" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
            <property expression="$ctx:query.param.qp" name="qp2" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
            <property expression="$url:qp" name="qp3" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
            <payloadFactory media-type="json">
                <format> {"Method1":"$1",&#xd;
"Method2":"$2",&#xd;
"Method3":"$3"}</format>
                <args>
                    <arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('qp1')"/>
                    <arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('qp2')"/>
                    <arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('qp3')"/>
                </args>
            </payloadFactory>
            <respond/>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence/>
        <faultSequence/>
    </resource>
</api>
```

when validating the code in the integration studio these problems appears:

```
Element 'format' cannot have character [children], because the type's content type is element-only. testapi.xml /test1/test1Configs/src/main/synapse-config/api line 9  XML Problem

The content of element 'faultSequence' is not complete. One of '{"http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse":call, "http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse":call-template, "http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse":drop, "http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse":log, "http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse":loopback, "http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse":property, "http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse":propertyGroup, "http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse":respond, "http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse":send, "http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse":sequence, "http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse":store, "http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse":conditionalRouter, "http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse":filter, "http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse":switch, "http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse":validate, "http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse":bean, "http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse":class, "http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse":pojoCommand, "http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse":ejb, "http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse":script, "http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse":spring, "http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse":enrich, "http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse":makefault, "http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse":header, "http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse":payloadFactory, "http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse":jsontransform, "http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse":smooks, "http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse":rewrite, "http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse":xquery, "http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse":xslt, "http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse":datamapper, "http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse":fastXSLT, "http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse":cache, "http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse":dblookup, "http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse":dbreport, "http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse":enqueue, "http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse":event, "http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse":throttle, "http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse":transaction, "http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse":aggregate, "http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse":callout, "http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse":clone, "http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse":iterate, "http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse":foreach, "http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse":entitlementService, "http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse":oauthService, "http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse":builder, "http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse":rule, "http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse":bam, "http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse":publishEvent, "http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse":NTLM}' is expected. testapi.xml /test1/test1Configs/src/main/synapse-config/api line 3  XML Problem


The content of element 'outSequence' is not complete. One of '{"http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse":call, "http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse":call-template, "http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse":drop, "http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse":log, "http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse":loopback, "http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse":property, "http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse":propertyGroup, "http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse":respond, "http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse":send, "http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse":sequence, "http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse":store, "http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse":conditionalRouter, "http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse":filter, "http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse":switch, "http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse":validate, "http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse":bean, "http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse":class, "http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse":pojoCommand, "http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse":ejb, "http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse":script, "http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse":spring, "http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse":enrich, "http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse":makefault, "http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse":header, "http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse":payloadFactory, "http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse":jsontransform, "http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse":smooks, "http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse":rewrite, "http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse":xquery, "http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse":xslt, "http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse":datamapper, "http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse":fastXSLT, "http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse":cache, "http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse":dblookup, "http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse":dbreport, "http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse":enqueue, "http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse":event, "http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse":throttle, "http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse":transaction, "http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse":aggregate, "http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse":callout, "http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse":clone, "http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse":iterate, "http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse":foreach, "http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse":entitlementService, "http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse":oauthService, "http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse":builder, "http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse":rule, "http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse":bam, "http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse":publishEvent, "http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse":NTLM}' is expected.   testapi.xml /test1/test1Configs/src/main/synapse-config/api line 3  XML Problem


Cannot find the declaration of element 'project'.   pom.xml /test1/test1CompositeExporter   line 3  XML Problem


Referenced file contains errors (jar:file:/D:/WSO2-Integration-Studio-8.1.0-win32-x86_64/IntegrationStudio/plugins/org.wso2.integrationstudio.gmf.esb.diagram_8.1.0.202211111317.jar!/resources/schema/endpoint.xsd).  For more information, right click on the message in the Problems View and select "Show Details..."   testapi.xml /test1/test1Configs/src/main/synapse-config/api line 1  XML Problem
```

I try to build rest api with wso2  integration studio

Comment: When you say `when validating the code in the integration studio` what option did you use? May be add the exact steps you followed. Also, some screenshots would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You have to delete those Caracters "&#xd" from your JSON Payload as below :

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<api context="/testapi" name="testapi" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <resource methods="GET" url-mapping="/testapi">
        <inSequence>
            <property expression="get-property('query.param.qp')" name="qp1" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
            <property expression="$ctx:query.param.qp" name="qp2" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
            <property expression="$url:qp" name="qp3" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
            <payloadFactory media-type="json">
                <format> {"Method1":"$1",
"Method2":"$2",
"Method3":"$3"}</format>
                <args>
                    <arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('qp1')"/>
                    <arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('qp2')"/>
                    <arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('qp3')"/>
                </args>
            </payloadFactory>
            <respond/>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence/>
        <faultSequence/>
    </resource>
</api>
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried to delete this those caracters  but the error still exists. Is there any other choise. Thank you